# NiFi v1.7.1 : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:null Error for custom processor

Tags: reflection, apache-nifi

I have created a Custom processor to use AWS Encryption SDK as a separate processor in NiFi version 1.7.1

I have implemented Abstract class with required Properties and createClient functions and processor main class with getSupportedPropertyDescriptors, onTrigger funtions.

But when I am trying to run the processor it gives below error:-

```
2018-08-15 23:15:39,732 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.p.a.encryption.EncryptorProcessor EncryptorProcessor[id=3eaf70a8-0165-1000-a4d1-6cfa42125382] Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:142)
at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:52)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.lambda$initiateStart$4(StandardProcessorNode.java:1499)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.AbstractAWSProcessor.createConfiguration(AbstractAWSProcessor.java:221)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.AbstractAWSProcessor.onScheduled(AbstractAWSProcessor.java:268)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.AbstractAWSCredentialsProviderProcessor.onScheduled(AbstractAWSCredentialsProviderProcessor.java:65)
... 15 common frames omitted
```

Versions:-
AWS Encryption SDK version - 1.3.1 
Nifi Version - 1.7.1 
Bouncy castle dependency version - 1.59

CodeBase outline:

AbstractProcessor:

- Has necessary properties declaration
- Client creation overloaded functions

ProcessorClass:

- init function
- onTrigger function with actual Encryptiop SDK Code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of AWS SDK and NiFi dependency do you use and if possible, a look at your custom processor's codebase will help

Comment: updated question with required details.

Comment: Which AWS SDK module? The AWS SDK being used in NiFi 1.7.1 is 1.11.319. Maybe it could be a version conflict. Try changing the version.

Comment: Actually i am using AWS Encryption SDK in particular. version being 1.3.1

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException at AbstractAWSProcessor.java:221` https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/support/nifi-1.7.x/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-aws-bundle/nifi-aws-abstract-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/aws/AbstractAWSProcessor.java#L221 I guess you provided not a full stacktrace....

Comment: no actually that's about it.. I have given full stack trace here!

Comment: strange. because at line 221: `config.setConnectionTimeout(commsTimeout);` where `config` used before, so it's not null, and `commsTimeout` is `int`, so exeption thrown somewhere inside `setConnectionTimeout` and nested exception must be present...

Comment: [GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15624285) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67078044) saying "See if the propertydescriptor TIMEOUT is missing in your processor propertylist. That helps me."